# deleting an employee conflicts with department manager foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-key-relationship

I created two tables , departments and employees with the following structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[departments](
    [department_id] [bigint] IDENTITY(10,10) NOT NULL,
    [department_name] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [manager_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [location_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [department_notes] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [created_by] [bigint] NULL,
    [created_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [last_updated_by] [bigint] NULL,
    [last_updated_date1] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [varchar](12) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_departments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [department_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_NoRepeat] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [department_name] ASC,
    [location_id] ASC,
    [status] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_departments_created_date]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [created_date]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_departments_created_date1]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [last_updated_date1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_departments_status]  DEFAULT ('Active') FOR [status]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([manager_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[employees] ([employee_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_departments_locations] FOREIGN KEY([location_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[locations] ([location_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_departments_locations]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Ck_deptStatus] CHECK  (([Status]='Deleted' OR [Status]='Active'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[departments] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Ck_deptStatus]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[employees](
    [employee_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [first_name] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [last_name] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [phone_number] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [hire_date] [date] NULL,
    [job_id] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [salary] [numeric](8, 2) NOT NULL,
    [commission_pct] [numeric](2, 2) NULL,
    [manager_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [department_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [allow_login] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [allow_email] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [driv_lic_no] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [reporting_to] [bigint] NULL,
    [salutation] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [date_of_birth] [date] NULL,
    [gender] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [blood_group] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Nationality] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [gov_id] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [passport_no] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [passport_expir] [date] NULL,
    [driv_lic_expir] [date] NULL,
    [perm_address] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [perm_city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [perm_state] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [per_zip] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [perm_country] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [current_address] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [current_city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [current_state] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [current_zip] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [current_country] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [mobile_no] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [notes] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [added_by] [bigint] NULL,
    [added_on] [date] NULL,
    [send_cred_by_email] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [user_name] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [employee_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_employees_allow_login]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [allow_login]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_employees_allow_email]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [allow_email]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] ADD  DEFAULT ('Mr.') FOR [salutation]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] ADD  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [send_cred_by_email]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY([user_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_AspNetUsers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_countries] FOREIGN KEY([perm_country])
REFERENCES [dbo].[countries] ([country_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_countries]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_countries1] FOREIGN KEY([current_country])
REFERENCES [dbo].[countries] ([country_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_countries1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_employees] FOREIGN KEY([employee_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[employees] ([employee_id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_employees_employees]
GO
```

there were some existing employees which are already managers in departments table , now when I try to delete any of those manager employees, I get a foreign key constraint conflict error blocking the delete statement. 
what is the problem please ?

Comment: Could you post the exact error?

Comment: No rows were deleted. 
A problem occurred attempting to delete row 4. Error Source .Net SqIClient Data Provider. Error Message The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FILdepartmen_manag_145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in database "hr", table "dbo.departments", column imanager_idi. The statement has been terminated. 
Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or press ESC to cancel the change(s).

Comment: The problem is that you cannot delete an employee if the department table still has a foreign key reference to that employee as the manager of the department. You need to switch to a different manager for that department first, or NULL out the foreign key in the department table before you delete the employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not allowed to do that.

A foreign key constraint is an integrity constraint meaning that it ensures data integrity across tables.

If one department row says that the ID of the employee that is the manager of this department is 73, it would not be good if there is no employee in the database with an ID of 73.

A foreign key constraint ensures this won't happen:

1. You cannot insert or update a department row to have a manager id that does not exist in the employee table
2. You cannot delete an employee that is referenced as a manager from a department row
3. You cannot update the ID of an employee that is referenced as a manager from a department row

The solution is to first fix the department by:

1. Switching to a different manager by updating the department row and adjusting the ID of the manager
2. NULL'ing out the manager, saying that this department has no manager, if that is allowed

After doing any of those two actions you should be able to delete the employee, assuming there's no other foreign key references as well.

Comment: what if I wanted the table to work like :
-each department should have 0,1 manager 
-whenever a manager is removed from employees table; the department becomes manager-less by deleting the manager id from the departments table.. 
how to implement this scenario?
thanks for your help

Comment: You would use `ON DELETE SET NULL` or similar cascade actions, see the syntax for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).